# expected ; (semicolon) on @page directive error (Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an Asp.net web page I got an error saying `; expected` referencing the `@page` directive. I don't know how it was originate, the only strange think I did was changing the page doctype. However removing it does not solve the error.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Mypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.Mypage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Removing the next lines it's still failing. I'm not able to open the page.

Comment: What is the code that immediately follows this line? When errors point to lines that can't possibly have the error, it's usually an incomplete token in a nearby line that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an `<img alt="icon" src='<% Eval("Icon") %>' />` that was not data bound what made it fail.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out everything in the code behind, then take everything out of the markup page and see if it works. Add back the markup chunk by chunk until you find the rogue character.

As Joel Etherton pointed out above, its something else in a nearby line.